# element has implicitly has an any type because expression of time any cant be used to index type

Tags: typescript

```
import * as emojiData from '../../emojify/emoji-data.json'
newEmojis.forEach((e: any) => {
    console.log(e)
    console.log(Object.keys(emojiData[e]))
    client.bot.createMessage(message.channel.id, `${Object.keys(emojiData.e)[0]}`);
})
```

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ "0": { "\uD83D\uDCA62\uFE0F\u20E3\uD83D\uDCA61\uFE0F\u20E3": number; "\u2755": number; "0\u20E3": number; }; "1": {
```

I'm not entirely sure whats wrong, or how I can fix this issue. I have tried setting the type of `e` from `any` to `Key`, as i wasn't sure if that was the issue. But that didn't seem to resolve the problem either.

`emojiData` is some data imported from a json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need to define a type for the `e` element

You can try with this code

```
interface JsonType {
  [key: string]: any;
}

newEmojis.forEach((e: JsonType) => {
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `e :any` to `e: Record<string, any>`